# floating background with css and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello all i was wondering how to achive a floating background image like we see on pintrest or may be this link https://sumally.com/ actually i have to design a page where i need to place two full hd background image vertically and need to scroll them vertically in background. users are access to form which is into another div placed on that image and fixed.

any help is appreciated

i think it can be done by

```
-webkit for mozilla
and for chrome etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

HTML

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="midground"></div>
<div id="foreground"></div>
```

CSS

```
#background {
    background: url(../images/background.png) repeat 5% 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

#midground {
    background: url(../images/midground.png) repeat 20% 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 200;
}

#foreground {
    background: url(../images/foreground.png) repeat 90% 110%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 300;
}
```

Javascripts

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.backgroundPosition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

      $('#midground').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
      $('#foreground').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
      $('#background').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});

        $('#midground').animate({
            backgroundPosition:"(-10000px -2000px)"
        }, 240000, 'linear');

        $('#foreground').animate({
            backgroundPosition:"(-10000px -2000px)"
        }, 120000, 'linear');

        $('#background').animate({
            backgroundPosition:"(-10000px -2000px)"
        }, 480000, 'linear');

    });
</script>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/Lx4upgpw/)